# How to escape “@” in the username when logging in through FTPES with curl?

Tags: curl, openwrt

```
$ curl -T "index.html" -k --ftp-ssl -u "MYUSER@MYDOMAIN.COM" MYDOMAIN.COM
Enter host password for user 'MYUSER@MYDOMAIN.COM':


 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 57173    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /index.html.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 Server at MYDOMAIN.COM Port 80</address>
</body></html>
100 57480  100   307  100 57173    284  52902  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 53633
```

Also [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650235/how-to-escape-in-the-username-when-logging-in-through-ftpes-with-curl) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641424/automaticly-upload-to-ftps/4649521)

Comment: Cross-posting is a no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i sniffed it with wireshark:

curl --ftp-ssl -T "FILE.TXT" -k -u "MYUSER@MYDOMAIN.COM:MYPASSWORD" "ftp://MYDOMAIN.COM"

and this one uses ftps! :P it works perfectly! solved :)

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `@` (you don't need to escape it), it's that you haven't told `curl` to use FTP in the first place. Note that you're receiving a HTTP response from a HTTP server.

cURL takes URLs, and if it encounters a bare `mydomain.com` it adds `http://` automatically. **Use `curl ... ftps://mydomain.com`** (which enables `--ftp-ssl` automatically, by the way).